# savefig - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Everything worked fine with my code 3 days ago, suddenly I get this error:

```
'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)'
```

when the run gets to this line: `plt.savefig(file.png)`

Comment: You should read [ask] and provide a [mre] in order to help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas In this case, that is the full error code. There is no TraceBack. The kernel just crashes; it's the nature of this particular issue. Some IDE's don't even give this much information, the kernel will restart and a new prompt appears without generating any other output.

Comment: better test code without IDE - directly in console/terminal `python script.py`. Maybe it will display more information. Maybe problem is only IDE, not code.

Comment: @furas in terminal, it briefly shows a blank interactive matplotlib window, which immediately closes, and returns to a prompt. No errors of any kind. The effects in multiple programming environments are documented.